# Arity overloading in Clojure source code

Tags: clojure

Here's the source code for `update-in`:

```
(defn update-in
 ([m [k & ks] f]
   (if ks
    (assoc m k (update-in (get m k) ks f))
    (assoc m k (f (get m k)))))
 ([m [k & ks] f a]
   (if ks
    (assoc m k (update-in (get m k) ks f a))
    (assoc m k (f (get m k) a))))
 ([m [k & ks] f a b]
   (if ks
    (assoc m k (update-in (get m k) ks f a b))
    (assoc m k (f (get m k) a b))))
 ([m [k & ks] f a b c]
   (if ks
    (assoc m k (update-in (get m k) ks f a b c))
    (assoc m k (f (get m k) a b c))))
 ([m [k & ks] f a b c & args]
   (if ks
    (assoc m k (apply update-in (get m k) ks f a b c args))
    (assoc m k (apply f (get m k) a b c args)))))
```

As far as I know (and I don't now much), this always gives the same result:

```
(defn my-update-in2
 ([m [k & ks ] f & args]
  (if ks
   (assoc m k (apply update-in (get m k) ks f args))
   (assoc m k (apply f (get m k) args)))))
```

My question: why isn't `update-in` (and many other Clojure functions) implemented this way? I would guess there are performance issues, ie. not using `apply` is faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you have guessed it correctly: some of the arities exist because of the performance cost of `apply`.

Having explicit arities for the most common cases (e.g. up to 3 arguments to the `f` function) improves performance as it translates to a direct function call.